# Return day int value from function

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

I try to write any code about days:

```
function xyz("13.02.2009")
{
    return value= 6;
}

function xyz("12.02.2009")
{
    return value= 5;
}

function xyz("14.02.2009")
{
    return value= 7;
}
```

But how?

This method is good but I need C# times specific codes (like timespan...)

```
DayOfWeek day = DateTime.ParseExact("13.02.2008", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DayOfWeek;
int days = ((int)day - (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
if (days &#60;= 0) days += 7;
Console.Write(days);
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that DateTime.DayOfWeek depends on your regional settings.

Answer (score 1):

It's `DateTime.DayOfWeek` what you need. And a decent C# book.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime day = DateTime.ParseExact("13.02.2008", "dd.MM.yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan difference = day.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
int days = difference.Days;
```

Comment: Dude, is it so hard to add "+ 1"?

Answer (score -1):

```
return (int)(myDateTime.DayOfWeek);
```